# How to remove extra space around text in a cell content in a td element?

Tags: html, css

I've some text in a `td` but somehow there's extra space around the left and the right side of the text. I've tried by putting `padding` to `0`, it didn't work but with images putting `padding 0` works. I've centered the text. Here's the image:

[image]

So, I want the td to be just big enough to fit 'beep beep' text.

Comment: provide your table code to help you

Comment: remove all padding or set padding to 0

Comment: @chirag he wants the width to be the same lenght as the text.

Comment: he just want "text". so remove all padding

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your text in a span inside the td.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of not any padding or margin of the text, usually the td stretch to cover the table width, if you make table width="auto" issue will solve.

```css
table{
  width:auto
}
table td{
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>dummy text</td>
    <td>beep beep</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```